# Prove or Disprove $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$ and $\int g_n \to \int g$ then $\int f_n$ converges to $\int f$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ be a sequence of integrable functions with $|f_n|\leq |g_n|$ for all $n$. Moreover, $g_n\to g$ and $f_n\to f$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Also assume $g$ is integrable and $\int_n g_n \to \int g$. Prove or disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n(x) dx= \int f(x) dx$.

I have tried to use dominated convergence but the problem is gn are not bounded necessarily. I've tried to come up with a counterexample where the limit oscillates... but again to no avail. Please help.

Comment: I think you need $g$ integrable or else you can take $g_n = f_n$, and the result is not necessarily true.

Comment: Hi, assuming g integral, how would we prove the result? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $g$ is integrable. Just run through the proof of dominated convergence Theorem. By Fatou,

$\int g - \int f = \int (g-f) = \int \liminf_n (g_n-f_n) \le \liminf_n \int (g_n-f_n) = \liminf_n (\int g_n - \int f_n) $
$= \int g - \limsup_n \int f_n$  (since $\int g_n \to \int g)$. So, $\int f \ge \limsup_n \int f_n$. Similarly,

$\int g + \int f = \int (g+f) = \int \liminf_n (g_n+f_n) \le \liminf_n \int (g_n+f_n) = \liminf_n (\int g_n + \int f_n)$
$= \int g + \liminf_n \int f_n$. Therefore, $\liminf_n \int f_n \ge \int f$.

Comment: hi thanks, how do we go from lim inf to lim sup?

Comment: Hi, it is a well known fact that for a sequence $(a_n)_n$ that $\liminf_n (-a_n) = -\limsup_n a_n$

Comment: @Socchi  See [properties of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties). Great answer!

Comment: hi, thanks you did not change the sign in the proof though?

Comment: so if should be + lim sup integral gn instead of - which would break the proof?

Comment: The proof is correct. $\liminf_n (\int g_n - \int f_n) = \int g + \liminf_n (-\int f_n) = \int g - \limsup_n \int f_n$.

Comment: oh yes thanks sorry

Comment: also why do you use lim inf inside the integral? we already know gn converges to g and fn to f, so why bot use limit instead?

Comment: This is what Fatou's Lemma says.

Comment: otherwise what a great proof, thanks!

Comment: i thought fatou just said lim inf integral <  integral limit but anyways limit inf and limit of fn are the same in this case

Comment: Hi, how is the following not a counterexample? Let $f_n(x)= n$  on $ [0,1/n]$ and $g_n(x)= n $on $[0,1/n] $and$ = -n$ on $[-1/n, 0]$... then $|f_n| \leq |g_n|$ but $\int g_n(x) = 0$ for all n and $g_n \to 0$ but $\int f_n=1$ for all n whereas $f_n \to 0=f$ so $\int f=0$?

Comment: @Socchi mathworker21's proof assumes $g_n - f_n \ge 0$ and $g_n + f_n \ge 0$ (or at least that these functions can be bounded somehow from below so that Fatou's lemma can be applied). If the functions $g_n$ and $f_n$ are themselves assumed to be non-negative, that's justified (the former because then $f_n = |f_n| \le |g_n| = g_n$) and the proof is correct. If you do not require such non-negativity, then that admits counterexamples such as yours (which is then correct instead).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This was written when the body of the question did not include the assumption $\int g_n \to \int g$.

Let

$$f_n(x)=g_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
n,&x\in[0,1/n)\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Then $f_n=g_n\to0$, and $\int f_n =1$ for all $n$ but $\int f = 0$.

Comment: Notice $g$ is integrable.

Comment: In the title of the question, it says $\int g_n \to \int g$.